# Powershell 5.1.17763.1007 How to execute a string-command stored in a variable (Copy-Item)

Tags: powershell

I have a simple tasks that doesnt work:

```
$Copy = copy-item -path "C:\Folder 0" -destination "C:\Folder $x\" -recurse

for($x=1; $x -le 9;$x++)
{
$Copy
}
```

I cannot execute the command in the variable $Copy, when I run the loop it just prints $Copy to the console as the variable seems to be empty.
I tried Invoke-Expression, & $Copy, putting the Copy-Item command under "", but that doesnt work here...

Any advice for a beginner?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Copy-Item` doesn't return anything by default, so the value of `$copy` is `$null`. You can't execute _nothing_. What exactly are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for your answer. I wanted actually just to store the command, so when I use it somewhere else that I dont need to type in the whole command. Would an Alias fit for my command?

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe you have the need to run the same exact copy-line more than once in the one script?

First thing that comes to mind for me would be something along the lines of `1..9 | foreach { Copy-Item -Path "C:\Folder 0" -Destination "C:\Folder $_\" -Recurse }` but it's kinda hard to tell when I don't know just exactly what (more/else) you intend to do.

Comment: @notjustme lets put it differently: I might have in the future a longer loop to create. Instead of writing code line by line, I would rather use aliasses for certain commands, therefore I would need to store the command somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, `Copy-Item` doesn't return anything by default, so the value of `$copy` is `$null`.

From your clarifying comment:

> I wanted actually just to store the command

If you want an executable block of code that you can invoke later, you might want to define a `[scriptblock]`. Scriptblock literals in PowerShell are easy, simply wrap your code in `{}`, and optionally supply parameter definitions:

```
$CopyCommand = {
  param([string]$X)

  Copy-Item -Path "C:\Folder 0" -Destination "C:\Folder $X\" -Recurse
}

& $CopyCommand 1
# later in the script
& $CopyCommand 2
```

or you can define a function with the same:

```
function Copy-MyFolderTree
{
  param([string]$X)

  Copy-Item -Path "C:\Folder 0" -Destination "C:\Folder $X\" -Recurse
}

Copy-MyFolderTree -X 1
# later in the script
Copy-MyFolderTree -X 2
```

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks a lot for your effort. I thought there is an easier way to store such a command and invoke it later in the code, but your both solutions are fine to me.

Comment: @notjustme Sorry if it wasnt clear. I think its a narrow path between just putting it straight what you want and writting an essay none reads. Still, thanks for your feedback. As working with PS and Stackoverflow I think I ll improve in future.

Comment: @Adis1102 "easy" is of course subjective, but "enclose in `{}`" seems pretty straightforward to me :)